# Search tasks by assignedToID, search tasks by time interval

Tags: attask, workfront-api

Trying to search tasks by `assignedToID` with `plannedCompletionDate` or `status` and for some reasons getting empty array though I know there are some tasks. Also I'm wondering if there is a way to search tasks by period of time like *01/01/2019 - 01/14/2019* ? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `assignedToID` has a unique property where only the first person assigned to a task or issue will be considered the assignee for that field. See if your objects have multiple assignees that could trigger this issue.

For date ranges, do something like `plannedCompletionDate=<start>&plannedCompletionDate_Range=<end>&plannedCompletionDate_Mod=between.`

Run a report with the fields you're using and ensure that you are getting the values you expect. Then start modifying your query one variable at a time until your results match.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to do a date range with the code you provided. For `assignedToID` - I had to fetch all records using `$$LIMIT` and then filter them on my end. Actually when I filtered them `assignedToID` did work locally(it had the correct id's for tasks).